# How to move emails to subfolders in coldfusion using <cfimap>

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using the below code but its not working, no error coming but emails not moving to the recommended folder.

```
<cfimap action="MoveMail" Recurse="true" newfolder="MainFolder/SubFolder" messagenumber="1" stoponerror="true" connection="connection">
```

Comment: Check the ColdFusion log files for any messages about the failure.

Comment: @Miguel-F there is no errors showing.

Comment: Try changing the forward slash to a period in your `newfolder` attribute as per this reference.  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-i/cfimap.html

Comment: @DanBracuk 
I used . instead of / but it still showing error message.below is the error
"This operation is not allowed on a closed folder"

Comment: Can you try providing the `folder="#source#"` attribute as well? I mean the source folder.

Comment: @RRK Thanks, it works for me.
<cfimap action="MoveMail" Recurse="true"  folder="MainFolder/SubFolder" newfolder="MainFolder/SubFolder" messagenumber="1" stoponerror="true" connection="connection">

Comment: I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

> This operation is not allowed on a closed folder

The error handling on `cfimap` is sometime very obscure. From my experience when I faced similar issue, the fix was to use the `folder` attribute to let the tag now from which folder we need to move the mail.

```
<cfimap
    action="MoveMail"
    Recurse="true"
    folder="SourceFolder"
    newfolder="MainFolder/SubFolder"
    messagenumber="1"
    stoponerror="true"
    connection="connection"
>
```